# How to create a collection view with single column?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to create a collectionView with 1 column

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```

But this didn't work.
And the main problem is my cell size changes dynamically. So can I restrict column to 1? I need to load the cells in rows, not in columns.

Comment: Can you share screenshot what you want to achieve? Or how it looks like now? And please add all collection view code here, as your main issue in size of item Right?

Comment: I hope u heard about TableViews `UITableView`

Comment: @KoushikGounder i heard about , i need to record the layout and cell animations is not as expected. In Collection view i can achieve it.

Comment: If column needs to be one only, using UITableView would be more appropriate...  What do you think?

Answer (score 6):

First you can use UITableView to achieve this functionality.
Second if want to use UICollectionView then :-

1) Select collection view in storyboard -> Go to properties -> set scroll direction -> Vertical
2) Set item size correctly

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, 
       layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
       sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
   {
       return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:YourCellHeight)
   }
```

3) Set appropriate Minimum Spacing for cell and lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you'd like your collection view to behave more like table view. In that case, I think contentInset is one you are looking for. If all your cells have the same width, and you can find out that width, you can do the following so that the collection view will always be in one column, centered horizontally.

```
let margin = (view.frame.width - cellWidth) / 2
let collectionViewInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: margin, bottom: 0, right: margin)
collectionView.contentInset = collectionViewInsets
```